# Changing Google Calendar Visibility Based On Organizational Unit

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-workspace, google-directory-api

Google Support Docs referred me to it's api, but that's it. Still new at Google API so any help is appreciated.

This is the situation I desire for my Organizational Units:
OU A: Can see Calendar Event info for all internal calendars. (Can set in the Admin Console)
OU B: Can only see Calendar Event info the user is a guest in. (Can't set in the Admin Console)

To clarify with an argument for OU B: Unless user is a guest of an Event, Show all events as "Busy"

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any code you're working on? Can you show what you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to solve a similar problem. Did you ever find a way to do this?